# Fancybox to open on link click only first time then go to page url

Tags: cookies, fancybox

I'm trying to gate a link using fancybox and cookies to show a form the first time the link is clicked and then once the form is submitted the popup form would no longer pop up but instead would open to the page url. Here is my code but so far all I can do is get the popup form to show on link click. How do I tell fancybox to not show if the cookie is present and instead go to a page link?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <link href="http://intercross2.com/CPS_landing_page/assets/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox data-src="#donation-info" href="thankyou.html" alt="">Fancybox</a>

  <div style="display:none">
    <div id="donation-info">
       <h2>Answer a few short questions to continue</h2>
        <form id="gate" method="post" action="sendmail.php">

    <label for="name">Your Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" title="Enter your name" class="required"><br>

    <label for="phone">Daytime Phone</label><br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="required"><br>

    <label for="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" title="Enter your e-mail address" class="required email"><br>


    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-link" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
      
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://intercross2.com/CPS_landing_page/assets/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      // Define cookie name
      var cookieName = 'hide_form';
  
      // Configure fancyBox
      $('.fancybox').fancybox({
          autoDimensions: false,
          autoSize: false,
          height: 'auto',
          padding: 20,
          width: 650,
         
          afterClose: function() {
            // Set cookie to hide fancybox for 1 day
            $.cookie(cookieName, true, { expires: 1 });
          }
      });
  
      // Handle submit click event
      $('a#submit').on('click', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault(); 
  
          // Hide fancybox and set cookie to hide fancy box for 7 days
          $.fancybox.close();
          $.cookie(cookieName, true, { expires: 7 });
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any element with *class* `fancybox` in your html code

Comment: I added the `fancybox` class to the link and updated the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do check if cookie exists, then use something like:

`if (!!$.cookie(cookieName)) {  /* Open fancyBox here */ }`

The rest is up to you.